# PHP equivalent of Python's __name__ == "__main__"?

Tags: python, php, program-entry-point, language-comparisons

As per the title, is there PHP equivalent of `__name__ == "__main__"`?

Is there something that would work for both scripts executed through the command line and through a web request, or would a custom function be needed?

For those unfamiliar with Python, `__name__ == "__main__"` allows you to define a module file, and also have some things that allow you to run it if it is the entry point. The equivalent structure in PHP would resemble this:

```
// SomeClass.php
<?php
class SomeClass
{
    function doStuff() {
        echo "wahey!\n";
    }
}

// python, I know.
if (__name__ == "__main__") {
    $sc = new SomeClass;
    $sc->doStuff();
}
?>

// OtherClass.php
<?php
require_once("SomeClass.php");
class OtherClass
{
    public $yep;
}
?>

// command line:
php SomeClass.php     // outputs "wahey!"
php OtherClass.php    // outputs nothing
```

---

**Note**:
[zerkms' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2414026/42223) is the best, but is not quite right - it should read:

```
if (!debug_backtrace()) {
    // do useful stuff
}
```

This is significantly faster than !count(debug_backtrace()), which itself is about twice as fast as my solution involving realpath().

Comment: what about my answer and count(debug_backtrace()) ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
if (!count(debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS)))
{
    // some usefull stuff
}
```

look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php for more details on debug_backtrace function

Comment: php_sapi_name() just tells me what the code is being executed in, which may provide a small part of the puzzle but doesn't solve the problem. I added some further information to the question to explain what I'm getting at.

Comment: ... or debug_backtrace() ;-) look at the comment to the question

Comment: Ahh, finally, I understand. debug_backtrace() works, and is thousands of times faster than the realpath. Update your answer to remove the reference to php_sapi_name() and update your example to read if (!debug_backtrace()) { /* do stuff */ } (or better) so I can accept.

Comment: There's no need to do the count - it's actually only twice as fast as the realpath() call if you do the count around it, as opposed to thousands of times faster if you do the simple truth test.

Comment: This is not the place to do optimizations. Your algorithms will work >10x times slower than this count(), but with count code become more obvious.

Comment: how does it become more obivous? "if (!debug_backtrace())" *clearly* says in code "if there is no backtrace then ...". so, micro-optimisation it may be, but why code something that's arguably no clearer and is slower?

Comment: because it become depending on implicit php casting array() -> false.
i think that explicit "if count of elements is 0" is more cleaner.
so i think the reason of using your case is only "readable from your point of view" but not "optimization issues"

Comment: I think we'll have to agree to disagree on this.

Comment: I'm with zerkms: The truth-tables for implicitly-converted PHP values are sufficiently large and full of edge-cases that it isn't very nice to whomever has to read your code later.

Comment: @Darien: with arrays->booleans it's pretty straightforward. `if (array)` is not tricky at all

Comment: No, it still unreliable because you can't always know (without more checks) whether you have a "real" array, or an object which implements array-access methods. I consider using `if($possibleArray)` a bit like using `==` for object comparison in Java: Can work, but not quite as you want.

Comment: Just FYI, there's an error in the code snippet, it needs an extra closing bracket at the end of the if condition. Won't let me edit it because edits need to be 6 characters or more.

Comment: Very very very bad answer... **NO** explanation at all. You see, programmers should never use code because it works, that's the wrose bad practice of all.

Comment: @iharob programmers have documentation in case if they don't know what a particular function does. Stackoverflow is not your personal tutor.

Comment: Yes but it's a Q/A site. At least some explanation would be nice. Posting just code is bad. Especially given the fact that PHP doesn't have the best documentation.

Comment: To optimize this a little, you can use `DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS` flag to reduce memory usage

Answer (score 14):

```
if ($argv && $argv[0] && realpath($argv[0]) === __FILE__) {
    // ...
}
```

works like a charm.

when you run php in command line, the name of php file will pass to program as `$argv[0]` and  `__FILE__` magic variable mean current file. So we check the running program is current file logically equals Python's `__name__ == "__main__"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(get_included_files()[0] == __FILE__) doStuff();
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want one of the "Magic Constants". Depending on what you are trying to do, `__FILE__`, `__FUNCTION__` or `__CLASS__` may give you the information you are after.

They are pretty self explanatory:

- `__FILE__`gives you the current file name
- `__FUNCTION__` gives you the name of the current function
- `__CLASS__` gives you the name of the current class.

Check [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) for more details

Comment: Probably, but how do I go about achieving what I am asking with those?

Comment: Looks like you've figured it out in your own answer :)

Comment: I think that `(realpath($argv[0]) == __FILE__)` might do it.