# PHP: main script vs. imported module

Tags: php, unit-testing, debugging

Dynamic languages tend to have features which allow for checking the way of using a module. Otherwise it would have been hard to unit test functions of the main script, for instance.

Python:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_main()
```

JavaScript:

```
if(require.main === module) {
  myMain();
}
```

Is there a way to do something like this in PHP? Sorry, it's a very newbie question, but I lack the right keywords, apparently.

Comment: What is it `module` in PHP?

Comment: This is part of my problem, yes. PHP must have its own word for the thing, but modules do exist. They are pervasive. So I've supplied examples from other languages to make myself clear.

Comment: Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413991/php-equivalent-of-pythons-name-main